# Error 500 when deploying ASP.NET Core 6 application on IIS (localhost is currently unable to handle this request)

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, .net-core, iis

I have created an ASP.NET Core 6 application and deployed it on IIS. My application works fine but when I go to login page, or any page that needs to get data from SQL Server, Error 500 is shown. I think there is no link between IIS and SQL Server. How can I fix this problem?

Update:
appsettings.json:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection" : "Server=(local)\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=ArtaCMS;Trusted_Connection=True"
  }
}
```

I have used Identity:

```
public class IdentityAppContext: IdentityDbContext<AppUser, AppRole, int>
    {
        public IdentityAppContext(DbContextOptions<IdentityAppContext> options) : base(options)
        {

        }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        }
        public DbSet<AppUser> Users { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Message> Messages { get; set; }
        public DbSet<PM> PMs { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Notification> Notifications { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ServiceType> ServiceTypes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<CostCenter> CostCenters { get; set; }
    }
```

Note that my App works fine in Visual Studio. The problem exists in publish. I have used Code First approach to create database.

Comment: Are you logging exceptions anywhere? The 500 http error just means you have an unhandled exception. It's likely related to SQL Server database access given the symptoms but, without exception details, all you can do is trial and error with guesses as to the cause.

Comment: @Gezgalee did you mean "appsettings.json" exists in the publish folder?

Comment: Post edited. Now, if you know the answer, please. @Larnu

Comment: We don't have the actual error yet though, @Gezgalee . Like I said a 500 error means "Internal Server Error" which could be anything. We don't know what line is erroring, what the exception is, or anything.

Comment: @Larnu My codes works fine when I use Visual Studio or VS Code. I have this problem in IIS.

Comment: Mr. @Fardin can you upload your project on github?

Comment: Did you handle errors? If not, follow https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: So something is different, @Fardon . Maybe you're using a trusted connection and the account IIS is running under doesn't have access to SQL Server. Maybe the server IIS running under is blocked by a firewall to the SQL Server. Maybe theres a permission error. Maybe you put the wrong credentials in for SQL Authentication, maybe... Maybe... Maybe... We don't have enough info to know what is causing the error as yet as for we have the *real* error.

Comment: Don't ask that, @Gezgalee . If the information is important it should be an [edit] to the question.

Comment: @Larnu I have turned the firewall off completely but nothing changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this connection string

```
"Data Source=(local)\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=ArtaCMS;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=True;"
```

after this you will have to create an application pool at your IIS
for example with name "ArtaCMS" and select "No Managed Code" and "Integrated" and select pool for your webapp. Open advanced setting and select "ApplicationPoolIdentity";

Open  sql server management studio and add a new user to your ArtaCMS database with type "sql user without login" and name "IIS APPPOOL\ArtaCMS"

Comment: I used your connection string. But the error exists yet.

Comment: Where should I add that connection string? in appsettings.json?

Comment: @Fardin Yes , replace the previous one.

Comment: I did what you said. But still says: localhost can't currently handle this request. Error 500

Comment: @Fardin Open application pool advanced settings   and select "ApplicationPoolIdentity";

Comment: Built-In account was on "ApplicationPoolIdentity". What option should I use?

Comment: @Fardin Leave as it is.

Comment: Do I need to select all Memberships and Owned Schemas in SQL Server?

Comment: @Fardin Open  Event Viewer on computer with IIS  and check WindowsLog => Application errors. Try to find IIS erros.

Comment: @Fardin yes, in SQL Server check dboowner membership at least

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to add the key value pair to the Configuration blade in the Azure App Service to get rid of the 500 error

Key: "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" Value: "Development"